# Unity is saying my array is overflowing and crashes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to write a piece of code that takes a money input and rewrites it with numerals (1000 to 1 thousand, 1,000,000 to 1 million, etc.) So far, I haven't been able to get past Unity telling me that there's a stack overflow on my array before it crashes, but I don't see why it's overflowing. Am I missing something huge or is something just not right here?
Unity has been giving me the error "The requested operation caused a stack overflow, MoneyTruncate() (at Assets/Scripts/Money.cs:60", which is the line pertaining to the array in this void.

````
    {
        string[] Numerals = new string[]{" ", "thousand", "million", "billion"} ;
        int i = 0;

        TotalMoneyFloat = (TotalMoney / (10 ^ (i * 3)));
        TotalMoneyFloatLimit = (TotalMoney / (10 ^ ((i + 1) * 3)));

        //current iteration of Numeral is correct- greater than current numeral, less than next
        if(TotalMoneyFloat >= 1 && TotalMoneyFloatLimit < 1)
        {
            TotalMoneyText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "$" + TotalMoneyFloat.ToString("0.00") + " " + Numerals[i];
        }

        //current iteration of Numeral is too high- less than current numeral
        if(TotalMoneyFloat < 1)
        {
            i--;
            MoneyTruncate();
        }

        //current iteration of Numeral is too low- greater than current numeral
        if(TotalMoneyFloatLimit >= 1)
        {
            i++;
            MoneyTruncate();
        }

        //i is at its limit for number of numeral available- i has reached max value for the array but money is higher than  
        if(i > 3 && TotalMoneyFloatLimit >= 1)
        {
            TotalMoneyText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "$" + TotalMoneyFloat.ToString("0.00") + " " + Numerals[i];
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Where/when is the posted code executed? In my small trace of the posted code… specifically in the last `if` statement… `if(i > 3 && TotalMoneyFloat <= 1) { …` … ? … From what I can decipher… `i` will NEVER be greater than 3. `i` will only be -1, 0 or 1. So I am not sure “why” you would expect `i` to be any other value than -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: The rest of the code has segments that call the function to print the money value to a text box whenever a "shop" ticks over and produces money:
`IEnumerator Stand1()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(GetComponent<Shop1>().Shop1Timer);

        TotalMoney += GetComponent<Shop1>().Shop1Revenue;
        CurrentTimerShop1 = 0;
        MoneyTruncate();
        StartCoroutine(Stand1());
    }`

Comment: Hmm… OK… So, the last `if` statement is for what? As I alluded to, the `if`s condition will NEVER evaluate to `true`… so its purpose is a mystery. The line of code… `TotalMoneyText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "$" + TotalMoneyFloat.ToString("0.00") + " " + Numerals[i];` … will NEVER get executed. Is this intended?

Comment: In the event the player gets into the trillions, it would result in 1,000,000,000,000/10^((3+1)*3) >= 1, and adding 1 to i for a result of '4'. This way, if the game is played long enough to be that high in money, it doesn't present the problem of going over i = 3 and instead caps the numerals as "$x trillions"

Comment: A stack overflow error typically implies an “endless” loop of some sort. I am implying that… In in the LAST `if` statement of your posted code … `TotalMoneyText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "$" + TotalMoneyFloat.ToString("0.00") + " " + Numerals[i];` … is NEVER executed, then it may be a candidate to check as problem for the overflow. In other words, since the text never gets changed and it needs to change to end some looping condition, then this would cause an overflow exception. Please put a break-point on that line of code and see if it ever gets hit… I am confident it will never get hit.

Comment: Adding a breakpoint showed the `if` never got called, but even removing it didn't prevent it from overflowing. The error is calling out the line containing the array still, so I don't believe it has anything to do with the last `if` statement at all.

Comment: If you are getting an index out of bounds error, then `i` is -1. As I said it can only be -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: It's not giving me an out of bounds, it legitimately says "The requested operation caused a stack overflow (>line with the array)" and putting in a condition to prevent i from being negative also doesn't change that. i shouldn't get to negative because it being "0" should fill any amount of money from 0-999, and money can't go negative

Comment: Have you traced the code? I am not that familiar with unity; and will bow out. You may want to show in which context the posted code is being called. And are sure that `TotalMoneyText.GetComponent<Text>().text` isn’t getting “checked” somewhere else after this code is executed? In other words, if `TotalMoneyText.GetComponent<Text>().text` does NOT get set/updated to some value, then the posted code will be called again? It appears that setting this value may be necessary and in its current context we already know it is NEVER getting set in the last `if` statement.

Comment: It’s important to note your title is misleading. Your array is not overflowing and crashing. Your code is going round and round itself like a snake eating its tail and that’s what’s crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What line is "line from the array"? What function is this? If I had to guess, you've got a circular reference somewhere here, which would happen if this function were called `MoneyTruncate()`.

The logic is not doing what you think it's doing and I would urge you to set a break point and step into every function. At some point you'll see that you keep coming through the same point in your code.

I would bet this function is named MoneyTruncate and you're trying to recursively call it, but your recursion is broken - your `i` variable is LOCAL and any decrement before recursion is not affecting the called child/recurring instance. This means the recurring instances follow the same steps, call the same function in the same way, and this goes on until your stack builds up so many function calls that it overflows.

You're using recursion to solve a problem that doesn't really need recursion. Just check if >= 1e12 and return trillion, 1e9 for billion, etc.

Comment: There are other parts that call this as the function to determine the numeral and print the money value into text, so it is called multiple times elsewhere. What you're saying is that since it's being called there and it can call itself, it's stacking too many instances of it and that's causing the overflow? I had also been trying to avoid using just a very large series of 'if' statements, but if this method isn't going to work I guess I may have to?

Comment: @Ignis196 it could work, but you're not really saving yourself much in the way of performance or readability by making it a recursive function. You've got what, three cases here? Thousand, million, billion? Four if you count trillion. Think about the amount of effort it would take to code up four if statements versus the amount of time you've spent trying to debug this. There is a time and place for recursive functions but they're as dangerous as a `while(true)` statement and you should feel anxiety when you write it.

Comment: I had intended to increase it to further numerals, but for the purpose of getting it working and testing it, I hadn't gone far. If that's the case, I'll scrap this and work out the case by case 'if' method instead. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ignis196 you do what's best for you, and recursion could definitely be an option here, but I don't think it's offering a compelling justification. Just my opinion though.